# How do I find the nearest Past or Future Date in an array of Dates by an DateObject?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

Let's say we have an Array of Dates

```
var dateArr = [new Date("Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200"), new Date("Sat May 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200")];
```

and an Date Object, which we need to search in the dateArr, for example:

```
var findDate = new Date("Mon Apr 05 2021 07:50:06 GMT+0200");
```

And all together we have  this PLUS

- a function to return us the nearestDate in
  dateArr by findDate which can lie in the past or future

```
var dateArr = [new Date("Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200"), new Date("Sat May 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200")];

var findDate = new Date("Mon Apr 05 2021 07:50:06 GMT+0200");

var result = getNearestDateInDateArrByFindDate(dateArr, findDate);

console.log(result); //should print to console: Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200

function getNearestDateInDateArrByFindDate(dateArr, findDate) {
   var nearestDateInPastOrFuture;

   ...

   return nearestDateInPastOrFuture;
}
```

What I tried  so  far without sucess ...

```js
var dateArr = [new Date("Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200"), new Date("Sat May 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200")];

var findDate = new Date("Mon Apr 05 2021 07:50:06 GMT+0200");

function getNearestDateInDateArrByFindDate(dateArr, findDate) {

        console.log(dateArr);
        console.log(findDate);

        var nearestFutureDates = dateArr.filter(dt => dt.getTime() >= findDate.getTime());
        var nearestFutureDates = nearestFutureDates.sort((a, b) => a.getTime() - b.getTime());

        var nearestPastOrFutureDate = dateArr.filter(dt => dt.getTime() >= findDate.getTime());
        var nearestPastOrFutureDate = nearestPastOrFutureDate.sort((a, b) => (findDate.getTime() - a.getTime()) - (findDate.getTime() - b.getTime()));

        console.log(nearestFutureDates);
        console.log(nearestPastOrFutureDate);
  //returns always sat May 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200
}


getNearestDateInDateArrByFindDate(dateArr, findDate)
```

And somehow  the snippet doesn't return Apr 01 but rather  April 31?

Comment: if you re using moment check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62380664/5909026

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please correct it if needed

Comment: Tried it now, also returns  me the wrong  rresult: sat May 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200

It seems  that it's only  looking at future  dates but i need past dates too!

Comment: Mostly unrelated but "Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200" is a non-standard date format. The interpretation is going to be implementation dependent and it's not guaranteed to produce the same date in all environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort by the difference in ms from each date to findDate.

NB: We can get the absolute difference in milliseconds between two dates using

```
Math.abs(date1 - date2);
```

So we'll use this to sort like so:

```js
var dateArr = [new Date("Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200"), new Date("Sat May 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200")];

var findDate = new Date("Mon Apr 05 2021 07:50:06 GMT+0200");

var result = getNearestDateInDateArrByFindDate(dateArr, findDate);

console.log(result); //should print to console: Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200

function getNearestDateInDateArrByFindDate(dateArr, findDate) {
    const sortedByDiff = [...dateArr].sort((a,b) => {
        // Sort by the absolute difference in ms between dates.
        return Math.abs(a - findDate) - Math.abs(b - findDate);
    })
    // Return the first date (the one with the smallest difference)
    return sortedByDiff[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter what is the nearest date on past and the nearest on future.

Optionally you can apply `.sort((a, b) => a - b)` to your array of dates if are not ordered.

```
const dateArr = [new Date("Thu Apr 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200"), new Date("Sat May 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0200")].sort((a, b) => a - b);
const findDate = new Date("Mon Apr 05 2021 07:50:06 GMT+0200");

const nearestPastDate = (dateArr, date) => {
    const pastArr = dateArr.filter(n => n <= date);
    return pastArr.length > 0 ? pastArr[pastArr.length-1]: null;
};

const nearestFutureDate = (dateArr, date) => {
    const futArr = dateArr.filter(n => n >= date);
    return futArr.length > 0 ? futArr[0]: null;
};

console.log(dateArr);
console.log(nearestPastDate(dateArr, findDate));
console.log(nearestFutureDate(dateArr, findDate));
```